# What does the green halo around Wizarding Challenges means?

Tags: wizards-unite

After completing a Wizarding Challenge, the fortress has a green halo around it for a few minutes.

[image: screenshot]

What does it means? Does it affect gameplay (like loot, difficulty...) in any way or is it just cosmetic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The green aura itself is purely cosmetic and does not affect the gameplay. When you come across a tower with this aura, it's to indicate there is a challenge either in progress or recently completed by you or another player. If there happens to be other players around, then you and the other players can team up to achieve better rewards.

**Sources**

- [EuroGamer](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2019-06-26-harry-potter-wizards-unite-fortresses-wizarding-challenges-rewards-runestones-2020)
- [iMore](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2019-06-26-harry-potter-wizards-unite-fortresses-wizarding-challenges-rewards-runestones-2020)